# Processing a string in a user-defined function

Tags: python, string, function

I have been asked to process a given string through a user-defined function in Python.

The goal is to take a string as input then split it into a list of the individual tokens, remove spaces, remove tokens that are only 1 character in length, convert each token to lowercase and then return a dictionary that displays each token and the count of occurrences of that specific token.

Example input: "Hello     world I am learning learning learning     Python"

Desired output: {'hello':1, 'world':1, 'i':1, 'am':1, 'learning':3, 'python':1}

I'm pretty new to Python user-defined functions so I could definitely use any help I can get. Here is my current idea:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

def count_token(text):    
    token_count = None
   
    # split the string
    tokens = text.split(" ")

    for token in tokens:
        # remove spaces
        tokens.append(token.strip())
        #remove word if only 1 character
        if len(token) <=1:
            token.remove()
        # convert to lowercase
        token.lower()
        return tokens
    
    # create dictionary that includes a count for every token
    token_count = {tokens : tokens.count()}
    return token_count


Hello = "Hello   world I am   learning learning learning     Python"
count_token(Hello)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
sentence = 'Hello I am learning learning python'

def counting_tokens(var):
    dc = {}
    tokens = var.split()

    for i in tokens:
        if len(i) <= 1:
            tokens.remove(i)

    for i in range(len(tokens)):
        tokens[i] = tokens[i].lower()

    for item in tokens:
        dc[item] = dc.get(item, 0) + 1

    print(dc)

counting_tokens(sentence)
```

There's probably a more succinct way rather than all the for loops but it works. You can use split to split the sentence into a list then just cycle through the list to remove 1 character words and change the case to lower. Then use a dictionary to count how many of each words you have.